# How to set value in datalist in HTML 5 using jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, datalist

I am filling a `datalist` using `AngularJS` . I want to select a value from the `datalist` using `JQuery`. How can i do that?

```
<input class="form-control" id="choose-arrow" type="text" list="sevlist">
  <datalist id="sevlist">
    <option ng-repeat="x in SevList">{{x}}</option>
  </datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` with datalists selected option selector:

```
$('#sevlist :selected').val();
```